# How can I write a JavaFX application that can update itself at runtime (Don't Stop the Application)?

Tags: javafx

I am currently developing a JAVAFX desktop application and also had the need to implement an auto-update mechanism.

Pack the updater application in the update itself.

**Application**: When the application detects a newer version it does the following:

1.Download update (Zipfile)

2.Extract all update file

3.Run updater

**ApplicationUpdater**: When the updater runs it does the following:

1.**Don't Stop** the Application

2.Copy the downloaded jar file to overwrite current Application

How i can update itself without stop application ?

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can not. You cannot overwrite existing files if they are currently in use. So if the application is running, you cannot overwrite its files. I'm not aware of any applications that do this.

Comment: Instead, you'd want either a [Preloader](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) or a custom loader you build yourself. Then, your users will start the application by running the `Loader`. It is the job of this `Loader` to download and install the updates, and then launch the main application.